# How to open an Sitecore Email Experience Manager email in browser

Tags: exm

I have a requirement to send an email with `View in Browser` link. On clicking the link, it has to open the mail in browser. We need to implement this by using EXM Template.

Is there a solution for this in Sitecore EXM?

Answer (score 1):

In a default installation, the Email Experience Manager (EXM) contains a number of predefined templates and import options. One of the predefined template is Newsletter : a template with a header containing a link to the online version of the email campaign and a footer with links to opt-out pages.

If you download EXM 3.4.2 from: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Email_Experience_Manager/Email_Experience_Manager_34/Email_Experience_Manager_34_Update2.aspx

you will see inside the package Email Experience Manager 3.4.2 rev. 170713 NOT SC PACKAGE.zip a zip file with the next name. **Email Experience Manager Sample Newsletter 3.4.2 rev. 170713.zip** . On this zip file is an example how to view newsletter in browser.

Normally you add the link in the header of the newsletter in this way:

```
@if (Request.QueryString["sc_pd_view"] != "1")
{
    <div style="margin: 10px 0; font-size: 10px; font-family: @Model.NewsletterOptions.FontFamily">
        @Html.Sitecore().Field(Templates.Header.Fields.ViewOnlineHavingTrouble, Model.ContentItem)
        &#32;
        <a href="/?sc_itemid=@Sitecore.Context.Item.ID&sc_lang=@Sitecore.Context.Language.Name&sc_pd_view=1">
            @Html.Sitecore().Field(Templates.Header.Fields.ViewOnlineClickHere, Model.ContentItem)
        </a>
    </div>
}
```