# Multisites View Message Online in Sitecore 9 EXM

Tags: exm

How to view the email campaigns online in a multisite solution? Because the link always redirects me to the default site (**Site1**) even when the email campaign was sent in **Site2 Email Root**

This is what I did:
 with the view email which I added in the header:

```
@if (Request.QueryString["sc_pd_view"] != "1")
{
    <div style="margin: 10px 0; font-size: 10px; font-family: @Model.NewsletterOptions.FontFamily">
        @Html.Sitecore().Field(Templates.Header.Fields.ViewOnlineHavingTrouble, Model.ContentItem)
        &#32;
        <a href="/?sc_itemid=@Sitecore.Context.Item.ID&sc_lang=@Sitecore.Context.Language.Name&sc_pd_view=1">
            @Html.Sitecore().Field(Templates.Header.Fields.ViewOnlineClickHere, Model.ContentItem)
        </a>
    </div>
}
```

In each Email Manager root per site, I added the baseURLS:
Site1: https://www.site1.com
Site2: https://www.site2.com

In /sitecore/system/Settings/Email/System/Hostname Mappings, Created two hostname mappings
[image]

But when I clicked the View Email Online link sent from **SITE2**, it always redirects me to the SITE1 url and only shows blank page.

Can you help me with this?

Below are the references:

[How to open an Sitecore Email Experience Manager email in browser](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6767/how-to-open-an-sitecore-email-experience-manager-email-in-browser)

https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/configuring_the_delivery_process/link_generation_and_hostname_mapping_in_exm

Comment: Please post your <sites> configuration

Comment: Are you logged into site2 cms when sending emails from site2 email root? I think that hostname mapper is working the way that this is required so it can map host correctly. Could you try this out?

Comment: @PeterProchazka, the URL is now site2 after logging into the site2 cms and sending the site2 from its email root. however, i still getting blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the need for hostname mappings in your case. The mapping settings on your email manager root should be sufficient.

Try to create or move your email manager root under your sites rootpath.

e.g.

- /sitecore/content/sites/site-A/<email-manager-root>
- /sitecore/content/sites/site-A/homepage
- /sitecore/content/sites/site-B/<email-manager-root>
- /sitecore/content/sites/site-B/homepage

Next have your siteconfig like:

```
<site name="site-a" rootPath="/sitecore/content/sites/site-A" startItem="/homepage" ... />
<site name="site-b" rootPath="/sitecore/content/sites/site-B" startItem="/homepage" ... />
```

Comment: Yes that's what I did. and sites are defined in site.config with the correct configuration for each site. Now the view email online has the right link but showing blank page.

Comment: The mail is in essence just another webpage with presentation details that can be called directly. Can you browse to it directly or preview it?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am able to make it work by publishing the site and language version of the email root that I'm working with. All in all the configuration is correct.